# How do i change the gamemode shown in the title screen?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made this map in minecraft. When I made the world I put it in creative so I can edit it and make it. The problem is how do I make it survival mode? I know /gamemode 0 but that doesn't change what's shown in the title screen.

I tired looking for a config file or something but found nothing.

Comment: You can try change that in MCEdit. That program can change pretty much anything about savegames, it should be able to do that as well.

Comment: Do you know how??

Comment: I'm at work right now so I can't tell you, and all minecraft related wikis are blocked here, sorry.

Comment: @private_meta your at work this late?!?! Do you know what i should search

Comment: First you can try Rokks answer. If that does not help you look for "mcedit change gamemode". Also, not evereyone lives in the US, it's 9 in the morning here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the world's level.dat using [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/840677-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac/) (NBTEdit is no longer supported). Find the gamemode, and change it to 0.

Comment: Can i use other programs like maybe notepad and change the 1 to a 0 and disable cheats

Comment: No, you need NBTExplorer, because the data is not stored in plain text. You can also use NBTExplorer to disable cheats, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that /defaultgamemode 1 will work